# How to get nested array value from Lua table

Tags: lua

If I want the value `home` then I can get the value doing like this: `phoneNumber[1].type`

But in real scenario I need to get the value dynamically

Can someone please help me to read the values of nested arrays in Lua

I have a json body like below,

```
Phone numbers{[

"Type":"home",

"Number":"1234456"

],

"Type:"personal",

"Number":"66666666"

]
```

Comment: Please post your Lua code to help us understand your problem.

Comment: Whatever "code" you have pasted here is neither valid JSON nor valid Lua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, you could use the following code to print the (key, value) of your `numbers` Lua table:

```lua
local numbers = {
  {
    Type = "home",
    Number = "1234456"
  },
  {
    Type = "personal",
    Number = "66666666"
  }
}

for _, number in pairs(numbers) do
  for k, v in pairs(number) do
    print(string.format("%s: %s", k, v))
  end
end
```

Output:

```bash
$ lua print_numbers.lua
Number: 1234456
Type: home
Number: 66666666
Type: personal
```

Comment: Generally the user gives input like phonenumber[2].type or any other nested array,  so in lua code we can take this user input and process this input and get the value of given nestedarray